# LINQ join behaving oddly

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, inner-join

I am attempting to perform a join between two tables and limit results by 3 conditions. 2 of the conditions belong to the primary table, the third condition belongs to the secondary table. Here is the query I'm attempting:

```
var articles = (from article in this.Context.contents
                join meta in this.Context.content_meta on article.ID equals meta.contentID
                where meta.metaID == 1 && article.content_statusID == 1 && article.date_created > created
                orderby article.date_created ascending
                select article.content_text_key);
```

It is meant to join the two tables by the contentID, then filter based on the metaID (type of article), statusID, and then get all articles that are greater than the datetime `created`. The problem is that it returns 2 records (out of 4 currently). One has a `date_created` less than `created` and the other is the record that produced `created` in the first place (thus equal).

By removing the join and the where clause for the meta, the result produces no records (expected). What I can't understand is that when I translate this join into regular SQL it works just fine. Obviously I'm misunderstanding what the functionality of `join` is in this context. What would cause this behavior?

**Edit:**
Having tried this in LinqPad, I've noticed that LinqPad provides the expected results. I have tried these queries separately in code and <strike>it isn't until the join is added that odd results begin populating</strike> it appears to be happening on any date comparison where the record occurs on the same day as the limiter.

Comment: Can you also post the 4 rows of data?

Comment: check out LinqPad if you haven't already

Comment: It might also help to see your schema.  The data types for metaID, content_statusID, and date_created might come into play as well -- and it's easy for me (somebody who's unfamiliar with your code) to make assumptions about those data types.

Comment: @hunter: In a complete wtf moment, I copied/pasted into LinqPad (awesome tool btw, thanks) and the same query works exactly as I expect it would.

Comment: @Dan Esparza: metaID (int), content_statusID(short), date_created (datetime).

Comment: @Dan Esparza: Actually performing a complete double-check, I found the type in SQL Server for date_created was DateTime (nullable).The type in the context file was Date (non-nullable). If you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it. Double-checking the types ended up being the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At your suggestion, I'm posting my comment as the answer:

> "It might also help to see your schema. The data types for metaID,
>   content_statusID, and date_created might come into play as well -- and
>   it's easy for me (somebody who's unfamiliar with your code) to make
>   assumptions about those data types."

Answer (score 2):

I can't seem to be able to add a comment but in debug mode you should be able to put a break point on this line of code. When you do you should be able to hover over it and have it tell you the sql that LINQ generates. Please post that sql.

Comment: Alternatively activate DataContext logging (e.g. `this.Context.Log = Console.Out`)